# How can I retrieve FolderID using SSJS marketing-cloud ssjs

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs

How can we retrieve the FolderID for emails, queries and data extensions using SSJS in marketing cloud ?

I couldn't find any value associated with folderID from returned array of emails, queries.

Anyone can help me on this please ?

Comment: can you give an example of how you are calling these: Core functions? WSProxy? SOAP calls? I believe most of those corresponding objects does have a 'CategoryID' inside them that is (despite the confusing name) actually the ID of the folder it is in.

Comment: I was unable to get it from core function, but I tried with customized ones and now it's working for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

CategoryId is SOAP property on object that holds this data. All objects that can be put into folders have it.

Comment: I was unable to get it from core function, but I tried with customized ones and now it's working for me. Thank you.